# Issues with the Material ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I found a strange issue with the Material Design ProgressBar in one of my Activities. The animation isn't really running smoothly as shown here: http://gfycat.com/RadiantFocusedAuk. It's worth mentioning that this only happens to one of my ProgressBars. Others are displayed as they should be.

The layout to this is quite simple:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_loan_statustext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/detail_loan_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detail_loan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to fiddle a bit with the style and it turned out that this behaviour will only occur if the Material-Style is used. Using the Holo-Style will make the ProgressBar animate properly.

Has anybody else had a similar issue?

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a problem in 5.0.0. The problem does not occur in 5.0.1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found something interesting in this [link](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#checkbox), i think it will solve your problem.

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndetermininate
            android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndetermininate"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="#1E88E5" />
```